# Observe text change in NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nstextview

I started to play with macOS development recently, and for last 2 days I'm struggeling with text views.

I have `Scrollable TextView`, which is `NSScrollView` (and `NSTextView` is it's `.documentView`). I need to do some actionevery time user change a text.

In iOS it's very easy. I just set `UITextView`'s delegate. However, I can't find anything relevant in documentation, nor here, regarding to `NSTextView`'s. No `textDidChange` or something.

Thanks guys, help appreciated.

Comment: try this. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextviewdelegate/1449303-textviewdidchangetypingattribute

Comment: @BenRockey The link points to `textViewDidChangeTypingAttributes` which is "Sent when a text view’s **typing attributes** change.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the text view's delegate. The delegate must coform to `NSTextViewDelegate`. `NSTextViewDelegate` inherits from `NSTextDelegate` (see relationships and `NSTextView` is a subclass of `NSText`). `NSTextDelegate` defines method

```
optional func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
```